# Selenium C#: How to get the properties/attributes of a class inside another class?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is a body of an HTML file

```
<div class ="pic">
  <a class = "img" href = "abcxyz.com">
  </a>
  <a class = "date" href = "asdfg.com">
     <span> Feb 02 </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is my code doing the job when I want to get the information like, get the image link

```
List<IWebElement> imgElements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("img")).ToList();
foreach (IWebElement imgElement in imgElements)
{
    img_URL = imgElement.GetAttribute("href").;
    Console.WriteLine(img_URL);
}
```

But now, what I want is, to get both links and info from class "img" and class "date". Please help me to optimize that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you need help with? You have the "img" class elements done and "date" looks like the same approach would work. Where is your "date" code?

Answer (score 0):

As both the classes `img` and `date` are in the same parent class `pic`, you can fetch both the values in a list using a common xpath and then iterate over that list to fetch the values that you want.
You can do it like:

```
List<IWebElement> imgElements = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//div[@class='pic']//a")).ToList();
foreach (IWebElement imgElement in imgElements)
{
    img_URL = imgElement.GetAttribute("href");
    Console.WriteLine(imgElement.Text);
    Console.WriteLine(img_URL);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but what I meant is I want also the "Feb 02", not just the hyperlinks only.

Comment: @maxrena you can print whatever you want to print from that element, i have added another line of code to print the text that is present in that element which would print "Feb 02" for the second element. Please pick the updated ans

Comment: I understand. But let's say if I want it to be in some kinds of formation like "img: abcxyz.com" "date: Feb 02". How would I do that?

Comment: @maxrena   `abcxyz.com` is the href and `Feb 02` is the text in your html. So what is the key that you want to display before them? Because if you want to display `img` then it is the `class` attribute. You cant merge class attribute with the text

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method for resolving specific tags, like this (I am using it for resolving labels):

```
public static IWebElement ResolveLabelFromElement(this IWebElement labelValuePairElement)
        {
            By by = By.TagName("label");
            var label = labelValuePairElement.FindElement(by);

            return label;
        }
```

And use like this:

```
var labelElement = element.ResolveLabelFromElement();
```